# How to remove the gap between each list-item in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Whenever I create a Unordered List, A gap remains below each of the list items.

What can I do to remove this?

Already tried 
**`margin : 0`**
 and **`padding : 0`** on both **ul** and **li**. The CSS reset of

> `*{ margin : 0; padding: 0 }`

also doesn't seem to work.

The gap can be usually removed in case of a horizontal list. But I'm at a loss how to accomplish this when I want a vertical list.

Comment: What do you have inside `<li>`? Actually, just paste the HTML.

Comment: I see no gap: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3MnNt/

Comment: @j08691 @developdaly : I've placed images within each of the `<li>`. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: Probably. How about posting your code or better yet, an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @j08691 Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn9fp/

Comment: Nevermind, @thirtydot's answer worked! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @j08691 @developdaly : I've placed images within each of the `<li>`.
>   Could that be the problem ? – maxxon15 6 mins ago

Yes. Yes, it could.

Add this CSS to remove the gaps:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The gaps aren't below each `li`, they're below each `img`.

Comment: Thanks. That works. :)

Btw, What ARE those gaps? margins, paddings or something else? I've removed them with the CSS reset!

Comment: `img`s are inline elements (like text). The gap is the space reserved for [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) in letters like `g` and `j`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that demonstration. I was completely in dark about those things before! :)